# What happened to the X's? Is their friendship over?

Tags: one-piece

During the whole of the Alabasta arc, the Straw Hat Pirates had wraps on their arms concealing that they all had a black "X" underneath for means for making sure that they could tell the real Straw Hat from the fake made by Mr. 2's devil fruit the Mane Mane no Mi. The "X"s were revealed right at the climax of the arc, when the crew was saying goodbye to Vivi, as a sign that they were still friends even though they couldn't say it out loud.

[image: "x" marks friends]

Well, as I was watching the anime, I noticed that it was not long after that the "X" disappeared off of the arms of the Straw Hat Crew. Is this just that time went on and they wore off or is there supposed to be some deeper meaning to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just because the Xs disappeared doesn't mean their friendship is over. The Xs probably simply vanished naturally; ink doesn't stay on forever, especially with how many battles the Straw Hats go through. Plus, Vivi is still keeping a close eye on what the Straw Hats are doing, which obviously means they're still friends.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of yelling, the pirates raised their hands to signify that they were already friends with Vivi. They wanted to shout, but the marines would go after Vivi if they knew she had connections with the pirate, so they raised their hands instead.
and that doesn't mean the mark is disappeared their friendship will also disappeared.